Contact role's related list on opportunities SALESFORCE
The problem doesn't show all the fields that are being chosen in the list
 I have added mobile field so it also displays 
The mobile field is not displaying on the related list infact none of the fields are being displayed in available fields
What can be done to modify this?

"Contact Roles" is different related list than "Contacts", what are you trying to do?
Contacts is for simple relations like company + employees. Contact Roles is when you have say branches/office locations of a company in Salesforce and say one contact is Head of HR in location 1 but VP of Sales on another (and you want them to still be 1 contact, 1 email and phone number).
If you really want to display some key contact fields on contact roles rel. list you could maybe create some formula fields to look the data up?
